# Creating a barplot in python seaborn with error bars showing standard deviation

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I am new to python.
I am analyzing a dataset and need some help in plotting the barplot with error bars showing SD.
Check an example data set below at the following link https://drive.google.com/file/d/10JDr7d_vhEocWzChg-sfBEumsWVghFS8/view?usp=sharing

Here is the code that I am using;

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_excel('Sample_data.xlsx')

#Adding a column 'Total' by adding all cell counts in each row
#This will give the cells counted in each sample
df['Total'] = df['Cell1'] + df['Cell2'] + df['Cell3'] + df['Cell4']
df

# Creating a pivot table based on Timepoint and cell types
phenotype = df.pivot_table (index = ['Timepoint'],
                values=['Cell1', 
                        'Cell2', 
                        'Cell3', 
                        'Cell4'], 
                aggfunc = np.sum, 
                margins = False)
phenotype

# plot different cell types grouped according to the timepoint and error bars = SD
sns.barplot(data = phenotype)
```

Now I am stuck in plotting cell types based on timepoint column and putting error bars = SD.
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you swap the rows and columns from pivot, you get the format you want. Does this fit the intent of your question?

```
phenotype = df.pivot_table (index = ['Time point'],
                values=['Cell1', 'Cell2', 'Cell3', 'Cell4'], 
                aggfunc = np.sum, 
                margins = False)
phenotype.reset_index()
phenotype = phenotype.stack().unstack(level=0)

phenotype
Time point  48  72  96
Cell1   54  395 57
Cell2   33  35  39
Cell3   1   3   9
Cell4   2   6   3

sns.boxplot(data = phenotype)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this is what I am looking for. Thanks for solution.

Comment: I have one more question. Is it possible to directly create this plot from the data table without converting it into a pivot table? If I use 'sis.barplot' then I am unable to select multiple columns for y-axis (i.e., Cell 1 - 4).

Comment: If what you want to draw is a time point on the X axis, you need to pivot to convert it. I don't think there's any way to draw it with the current data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is one of the plot that I want to generate. Secondly, I want another plot in which I want to show each cell type alongwith the timepoints (eg, in graph, timepoint 1 should show 4 bars of each cell type 1 to 4 (with error bars) and similar for other two time points. Is sns.barplot is the right option to use for it here?

Comment: If the data in the separate plot is the same as it was before the `pivot_table', I think you can create a bar plot.